# 'TypeError: illegal operation attempted on a revoked proxy' when using Immer with setState

Tags: reactjs, typescript, immer.js

I recently refactored my React App to use [Immer](https://github.com/mweststrate/immer). However, in the `onFormValueChange` using `produce` gives me the error `TypeError: illegal operation attempted on a revoked proxy` while the version that is written without `produce` works fine.

This is the smallest I could reduce the relevant code to :

---

**test.tsx**

```
import { produce } from 'immer';
import { IFormValues, TestForm } from './test_form';

interface ITestProps {}

interface ITestState {
  type: string;
}

export class Test extends React.Component<ITestProps, ITestState> {
  constructor(props: ITestProps) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      type: '',
    };
  }

  handleSubmit = (values: IFormValues) => {
    console.log.log(values);
  };

  onFormValueChange = (values: IFormValues) => {
    this.setState(
      produce((draft: ITestState) => {
        draft.type = values.type;
      }),
    );
  };

  // The Following version of the function works perfectly fine and as expected:
  //
  // onFormValueChange = (values: IFormValues) => {
  //   this.setState({
  //     type: values.type,
  //   });
  // };

  render() {
    let showField = true;
    if (this.state.type === 'test') {
      showField = false;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <TestForm
          submit={this.handleSubmit}
          onValueChange={this.onFormValueChange}
        >
          <input name="type" />
        </TestForm>

        {showField && this.state.type}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**test_form.tsx**

```
import produce from 'immer';

export interface IFormValues {
  [key: string]: any;
}

interface IFormProps {
  submit: (values: IFormValues) => void;
  onValueChange?: (values: IFormValues) => void;
}

export interface IFormState {
  values: IFormValues;
}

interface IFieldProps {
  value: any;
  name: string;
  onChange: (event: any) => void;
}

export class TestForm extends React.Component<IFormProps, IFormState> {
  constructor(props: IFormProps) {
    super(props);

    const values: IFormValues = {};

    this.state = {
      values,
    };
  }

  private handleSubmit = (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const { submit } = this.props;
    const { values } = this.state;

    submit(values);
  };

  handleChange = (event: any) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    this.setState(
      produce((draft: IFormState) => {
        draft.values[name] = value;

        this.props.onValueChange && this.props.onValueChange(draft.values);
      }),
    );
  };

  public render() {
    const { values } = this.state;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} noValidate={true}>
        <div>
          {React.Children.map(
            this.props.children,
            (child: React.ReactElement<IFieldProps>) => (
              <div>
                {React.cloneElement(child, {
                  value: values[child.props.name],
                  onChange: this.handleChange,
                })}
              </div>
            ),
          )}
          <div>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You're right, my mistake...Edited the question.

Comment: *"However, in the onFormValueChange using produce gives me the error TypeError: illegal operation attempted on a revoked proxy."* It's still not clear that that's where the error *originates*, or if it's just using it there makes the error happen. In particular I wonder if the error *originates* in `handleChange` in `TestForm`.

Comment: Well the problem is that I wrote two versions of the `onFormValueChange` functions. One with and one without using `produce` and only on using `produce` do i get this error. As for where the error originates, I am not certain. I can post the stacktrace if you like, but React stacktraces just..aren't the best.

Comment: :-) Even if there's a bit of a forest-for-the-trees thing with React stack traces, it should be possible to tell from the trace whether `handleChange` is in the call stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caveat: I've never used Immer. But the error is quite clear: You're trying to use a revoked Proxy. My guess is the fundamental problem is here:

```
this.setState(
  produce((draft: IFormState) => {
    draft.values[name] = value;

    this.props.onValueChange && this.props.onValueChange(draft.values); // <=======
  }),
);
```

In `produce`, you're passing `draft.values` into a function that will call `produce` a second time and put `values.type` on a *different* draft state. My guess is you're not allowed to pass data out of the original `produce` call in that way. ([The documentation](https://github.com/mweststrate/immer) says *"Warning: please note that the draft shouldn't be 'leaked' from the async process and stored else where. The draft will still be revoked as soon as the async process completes."* but that warning is in relation to async producers, and yours aren't async. Still, it may be that it's a more general warning, it just happens to be in the async producers part.)

If so, this change to `handleChange` in `TestForm` would fix it:

```
this.setState(
  produce((draft: IFormState) => {
    draft.values[name] = value;
  }),
  () => {
    this.props.onValueChange && this.props.onValueChange(this.state.values);
  }
);
```

That ensures that it calls `onValueChange` with the value *after* the state has been set (presumably it's a normal object at that point, not a proxy).

Comment: This did fix it..Although I'm not sure exactly why. Just to confirm, the error was that I was using a reference to `draft` which is not supposed to be done since it is revoked as soon as the state change is finished completing?

Comment: @ManavM - That's what I think was happening, yes. (Well, not to `draft`, but to `draft.values`). The `draft.values` within the producer callback in `handleChange` would appear to be a Proxy. By passing it (indirectly) to `onFormValueChange` you're copying it out of the producer that uses it. My guess is the error occurs when both `produce` calls have completed and React tries to use the state from `onFormValueChange`, accessing a now-revoked Proxy. Or something along those lines. I think the take-away message is: Don't send draft state out of the producer callback. :-)

Comment: I see...Thank you for taking the time to explain :)